# how to add the imported component with js？

Tags: javascript, aframe

```
(function test() {
  var el = document.createElement('a-entity');
  document.querySelector('a-scene').appendChild(el);
  el.setAttribute(' text-geometry', {
    value: '你',
    font: '#optimerBoldFon'
  })
  el.setAttribute(' material', {
    color: '#66E1B4'
  })
  el.setAttribute(' position', {
    position: '-4 2 2'
  })


})() //wrong
```

this way works

```
<a-entity text-geometry="value: 你; font: #optimerBoldFont" material="color: #66E1B4" position="-4 2 -411"></a-entity>
```

[image]

Can someone tell me why? Or tell me how to do it?

Comment: What framework/library are you using ?

Comment: Why the  leading blanks in `el.setAttribute(' text-geometry'`

Comment: Also do you execute the script AFTER `a-scene` exists in the DOM

Comment: Also spelling of `optimerBoldFon`

Comment: As mentioned above, attribute names cannot have leading spaces and you are doing `el.setAttribute(' text-geometry')` That is what causes the error `is not a valid attribute name...`

Comment: @DiegoMarcos That could be ans answer ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like it's those spaces that are catching you out - `el.setAttribute("material", { //stuff });` would work, but `el.setAttribute(" material"` wouldn't...